# Infinite-Scroll Plugin and Jetpack Infinite Scroll Plugin - Adding to "Thoughts" Theme

Tags: php, loop, customization, widgets, jquery

How do I enable infinite scroll (either with the infinite-scroll plugin OR the built in infinite scroll jetpack) on the "Thoughts" Wordpress theme?

I'm a total noob at editing this stuff so if you are kind enough to help please keep it very simple as if I do not know anything.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really get any better than the [Jetpack Infinite Scroll Documentation](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/).  This is about as easy and user friendly as any of us could make it, and far more in depth.  I did this to one of my blogs recently, and it basically uses AJAX (Asynchronous Java script) to call a bit of PHP you have stored in a "content" file, which is essentially your loop, when you get to the bottom of the page.  It's fairly straightforward if you are even slightly familiar with editing WordPress theme files.